# validando grupo de radios en javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function validarradios() {    
        var tab1 = $("#parte2").val(); --> vale 6 <br> 
        var list = new Array();

        for (var x = 0; x < tab1; x++) {
            var lsGrupo = "grupo3_" + x;
            var objGrupo = document.getElementsByName(lsGrupo);
            for (var i = 0; i < objGrupo.length; i++) {
                if (objGrupo[i].checked) {                    
                    if (i == 0) {
                        list.push("Bueno");
                    }
                if (i == 1) {
                    list.push("Malo");
                }
                if (i == 2) {
                    list.push("No Aplica");
                }
               }              
            }          
        }
    alert(list);          
    }
```

no se porque cuando (x) vale 6 se sale del ciclo y no me valida la ultima posición y hasta le coloque  `for (var x = 0; x <= tab1; x++)` y nada... de ante mano gracias.

---

Lo que pasa es que el la tabla que tengo dinamica cuando el recorria para buscar el grupo de radios x y encontraba una cabecera donde no tenia grupo de radios solo la pregunta inicial para responder las demas el ciclo al final no validaba el grupode radios ya que no existia e incrementaba el indice al final, lo que hice fue crear otra validacion en codigo razor para no incrementar el indice cuando encontrara una cabecera.

Comment: Hola @Heiner. Veo que comentaste que ya resolviste tu problema. Sería genial si pudieses publicar la respuesta o, si era un error no reproducible, como por ejemplo si no existe la función `getElementsByName`, votar para cerrar la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El loop `for` tiene la instrucción de no llegar a 6. Puedes resolverlo de un par de formas:

```
for (var x = 0; x < (tab1 + 1); x++) {
```

O así:

```
for (var x = 1; x < tab1; x++) {
```

O así:

```
for (var x = 0; x <= tab1; x++) {
```

Por otro lado, usa `console.log()` para saber si al menos inicia el loop.

```
for (var x = 1; x < tab1; x++) {
console.log(x);
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda ya lo resolví.

Comment: Que bueno saberlo ¿fue ésta la respuesta correcta? en caso de serlo, por favor selecciónala, de lo contrario deberías publicar la respuesta correcta y aceptarla para cerrar el ciclo. Saludos.